# How to solve this Non linear optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I need to minimize the below-mentioned expression.

$   L = min (a_0-b_0*(p_1+p_2))^2 + (p_1*y1+p_2*y)$ ,with

```
            s.t p_1 >=0 ,p_2 >=0
```

Here variables are $p_1$ and $p_2$

So I tried using KKT as both the expression and constraint are convex.
But l was not able to come with the generalized result over $p_k$ where $k = 1,2,3..$

In the expression I have used $k=2$ .

if $k = 3$ :

```
L = min (a0-b0*(p1+p2+p3))^2 + (p1*y1+p2*y2+p3*y3)

            s.t p1>=0,p2>=0,p3>=0
```

Basically I used KKT,

Then considered 4 cases p1>0 && p2>0 ,p1>0 &&p2==0 ,p1==0&&p2>0 ,p1==0 && p2==0.

Can any one show me the steps to get the generalized result.

Comment: To compute the KKT, the procedure is the same whatever the case you take ($k=2, k=3$ or $k=100$). The difference is just the size of the linear systems obtained by computing the derivatives of Lagrangian functions.

Comment: @AlexSilva Yeah I Know but I tried to solve it for k=2 so that I could generalize for any k.But I failed to derive a general form of $p_k$

Comment: @AlexSilva the system is not linear, due to the sign constraints. I suggest you start assuming $y_1 \geq y_2 \geq \ldots \geq y_k$.

Comment: @LinAlg, I did not get the non-linearity of the system. The derivative of the Lagrangian $L'$  seems to be linear. For example, $$\frac{\partial L'}{\partial p_k} = -2b_{0} \left(a_0-b_0 \sum p_k \right)+ y_k - \mu_{k},$$ where $\mu_{k}$ is the lagrange multiplier associated to the constraint $-p_{k} \leq 0$.

Comment: @AlexSilva you are right about the stationarity conditions, but the KKT system also includes (nonlinear) complementary slackness conditions, as well as linear *in*equalities $p \geq 0$ and $\mu \geq 0$ for primal and dual feasibility.

Comment: @AlexSilva you are correct on derivative. After this i considered the 4 different cases as mentioned above for case k=2 i.e $p_1$ and $p_2$.In first case i.e both greater than zero their we get $y_1$ = $y_2$.Butcould not get value of $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: You are right. I forgot the non-linear constraints $\mu_{k}p_{k}=0$.